# Resume from the Cell with newly entered Data by a Userform

Tags: excel, userform, resume, data-entry, vba

I am taking over a macro for someone, trying to re-code it, and they the userform to take off from the newly entered data cell. Here is 1 userform (there are multiple userforms within this macro)

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.ComboBox2.List = Sheets("Lookups").ListObjects("HilvlActivitySourceLookup").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

ActiveCell.Value = ComboBox2.Value
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub EndButton_Click()
End
End Sub
```

I was considering adding some code underneath `Command Button 2`, similar to:

```
rem process userform data
    UserEntryFromUserform = Userform1.ListBox1.Value
```

But am not sure if I am approaching this the right way. There are multiple userforms, all coded similarly, and if you could give some suggestions on how to automatically resume, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `rem` is a cmd batch file method.

Comment: @Jeeped, True, I was considering a function, but not sure if that would work...